# How to run a batch file on all files in a folder?

Tags: python, xml, pandas, batch-file

I have a python script that I use to parse my xml files one by one, I run it with a batch file on windows CMD. My `script.py` is like that:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Read one xml file of Dedcoded directory
tree = ET.parse('C:/Users/sky/Documents/title_file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

CODE = [ ]
for errors in root.findall('.//Data/Record/Field[11]/BitField'):
    error = errors.find('Name').text
    error_code = errors.find('RawValue').text
    if error_code is not None:
        CODE.append(error_code)

dftest = pd.DataFrame(CODE, columns=['Error_Code'])

dftest['I_F_Name'] = root.find('./Header/InitialFileName').text
dftest['AC_prog'] = root.find('./Header/ACProgram').text
dftest['Standard'] = root.find('./Header/Standard').text

dftest.to_csv('sh_test.csv', mode='w', header=True, index=False)
```

It works perfectly for a single xml file, but I have a lots of xml files and I want to process them one by one automatically. For that I add a `for loop` in my `file.bat` and when I run it on CMD, it processes several time the same file which is given in `script.py`. There is my batch script:

```
@echo of
for /R C:/Users/sky/Documents %%f in (*.xml) do C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\python.exe C:/Users/sky/Documents/script.py %*
pause
```

I don't know what should I modify in my `script.py` or `file.bat` to process all my file one by one?

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: you can use `os.walk()` in your python instead of looping in the bat file

Comment: You should modify your `script.py` to accept a file or directory input parameter, *(which can be passed as necessary from a batch file or the command line)*

Comment: @Compo what should I modify in my `script.py`?

Comment: @anishtain4 could you give an example plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the static xml file in the python code by the argument the .bat file is sending.

Example

```
import sys
# ...
tree = ET.parse(sys.argv[1])
# ...
```

You'd also need to change you bat file:

```
@echo of
for %%f in (C:\Users\sky\Documents\*.xml) do C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\python.exe C:/Users/sky/Documents/script.py %%f
pause
```

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: @Pau Franco, Thanks it works perfectly, just at the end of `file.bat` you forgot a `%` for `%ff`.

Comment: @KamiKaze, [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) stores the list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.

Comment: I added the missing `%` to the answer. Hope that it's well this time.

Comment: @Mallenat This is not something I would like to know, I said that so you can edit it into your answer, so people understand what these changes do. It would be great if your answer gives a bit more detail what the effect of the changes are.

Comment: @Mallenat, How can I modify my last line of code to dftest.to_csv('sh_test.csv', mode='w', header=True, index=False) to write data just once with header and the others without header and just append them on my CSV file? When I change the mode='a’ then I get the header several times.

Comment: @M-M, I don't have experience working with panda, but you should check if the CSV exists:
    `if os.path.isfile('sh_test.csv'):
        dftest.to_csv('sh_test.csv', mode='w', header=True, index=False)
    else:
        dftest.to_csv('sh_test.csv', mode='w', header=False, index=False)`

I don't know if `to_csv` overwrites the files, it should work if it appends to the file.

Comment: @Mallenat, i solved my problem:

`if os.path.isfile('sh_test.csv') is False: 
 dftest.to_csv('sh_test.csv', mode='w', header=True, index=False) 
else: 
 dftest.to_csv('sh_test.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)`

This one works prefectly.